# Count unique words in a text file (Python)

Tags: python, file-io

I am new to Python so I'm doing some challenges and one of them is to find the number of unique words in a text file. The text file has 212 unique words in it but with the code I have it only shows 0. thank you for your help.

```
words=[]
count=0
with open ("text.txt","r") as file:
  for line in file:
    if line in words:
        words.append(line)
        k+=1
    else:
        pass
print(k)
```

Comment: What is `k` and why are you incrementing it?

Comment: Your if condition is wrong. You need to say `if not line in words`, currently because none of the words exists on the words array its simply doing the `pass` statement. Speaking of the `pass` statement, I dont think you need the whole else statement. Also finally how is 'k+=1' working, when you haven't instantiated the variable `k` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the code snippet, since `k` is not declared. I am assuming you were trying to `count` the number of unique words instead.

Also, there are better ways to find unique values in a list by converting it into a set. Values in a set will not contain duplicated values.

Check out the code snippet below.

```
words = []
count = 0

with open ("text.txt","r") as f:
    # Get a list of lines in the file and covert it into a set
    words = set(f.readlines()) 
    count = len(words) 

print(count)
```

Comment: Wow this is the first real world use case of using python `set()` function, that I have ever seen. Good solution. Just want to add, the empty array declaration for words on line 1 may no longer be needed with your solution.

Comment: This implementation doesn't work if there's more than one word per line.

Answer (score 0):

Change to if line not in file, you want to add the word if it is not in your list yet, and ignore it if it is already there

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit wrong in your example snippet:

- It's more performant to use a `dict` or `set` in this case than a `list`
- You aren't splitting words on each line (if there's more than one word per line)
- Your `else` condition is unnecessary

Here's a simple implementation that fixes these issues, and uses a few neat language features:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

    uniques = set()
    for line in lines:
        uniques |= set(line.split())

    print(f"Unique words: {len(uniques)}")
```

This example uses [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) and f-strings, the latter of which is only available in Python 3.6+. Note, however, that we're "slurping" the entire file contents into a variable, which could be bad if the file is very large. I'm assuming that your example file is small.

Also, this example doesn't handle cases like punctuation and the like. So, "test" will be counted as a different word than "test." (with a period). Fixing that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
file = open("names.txt", "r")
read_data = file.read()
words = set(read_data.split())
for word in words:
    count += 1
print('Total Unique Words:', count)
```

replace names.txt with your file name